# Change static google chart [Bar Chart] background-color

Tags: google-visualization

I need to change the background-color of the google static chart for bar graph. Anyone has any solutions?
Right now the color is white [#ffffff]

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bhs&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a parameter like

```
chf=bg,s,ff0000
```

[image]

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bhs&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World&bg=FF0000&chf=bg,s,ff0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you've tagged this as a CSS/HTML question, after reading through the documentation on Google, javascript might be a better to implement this. In your javascript code, include this:

```
    var options = {

      //The background color for the main area of the chart. Can be either a simple HTML color string, for example: 'red' or '#00cc00', or an object with the following properties.
      backgroundColor: 'black',

      //The color of the chart border, as an HTML color string
      backgroundColor.stroke: 'blue'

     //The chart fill color, as an HTML color string
      backgroundColor.fill: 'yellow'
    };
```

Remove whatever isn't necessary. I included a few extra customization options.

Source: [Google chart tool documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options). There are more customization options available there.

Comment: The page i'm creating has to go in the email. It's an email newsletter. Map has to be static. Can't use javascript.